# SQL Querying: How to Find the Maxima of Certain Columns within Different Sets of Similar Records?

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I find all the secret ingredients that were used in my pizzas which have won a prize? I’m missing the SQL condition in the comment below:

```sql
 SELECT r.name, p.secret_ingredient FROM restaurants AS r
 JOIN restaurant_has_pizzas AS rhp ON rhp.restaurant_id = r.id
 JOIN pizzas AS p ON p.id = rhp.pizza_id
 JOIN awarded_prizes AS a ON a.id = r.latest_prize_id
 WHERE r.owner = 'me!'
   AND p.created_at < a.won_at
-- AND p is as young/new as possible, i.e., p.created_at is as close to
--   a.won_at as possible; I’m only interested in the winning pizzas which
--   have been made right before the taster awarded us a prize!
 ;
```

The query so far returns all kinds of ingredients that were used in restaurants which have won a prize. However, I’m only interested in *those* secret ingredients that were used in winning pizzas. Note that my chefs have all created newer pizzas since we have won the last prizes.

Here’s the DDL:

```sql
CREATE TABLE pizzas
    (`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `created_at` DATETIME NOT NULL,
     `secret_ingredient` VARCHAR(42) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
;
INSERT INTO pizzas
    (`created_at`, `secret_ingredient`)
VALUES
    ('2012-11-01', 'peas'),
    ('2012-12-01', 'pepper'),
    ('2012-12-11', 'pork'),
    ('2012-12-21', 'peanuts'),
    ('2012-12-31', 'oranges'),
    ('2013-01-02', 'ham'),
    ('2013-01-20', 'oranges'),
    ('2013-01-21', 'root beer'),
    ('2013-03-22', 'mushrooms')
;

CREATE TABLE awarded_prizes
    (`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `won_at` DATETIME NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
;
INSERT INTO awarded_prizes
    (`won_at`)
VALUES
    ('2012-12-23'),
    ('2013-02-02')
;

CREATE TABLE restaurants
    (`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `name` VARCHAR(42) NOT NULL,
     `owner` VARCHAR(42) NOT NULL,
     `latest_prize_id` INT,
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
     CONSTRAINT `fk_restaurants_awarded_prizes1`
       FOREIGN KEY (`latest_prize_id`)
       REFERENCES `awarded_prizes` (`id`))
;
INSERT INTO restaurants
    (`name`, `owner`, `latest_prize_id`)
VALUES
    ('Don Camillo', 'me!', 1),
    ('Tasty Pizzas', 'me!', 2),
    ('B. R.', 'Don Alphonso', NULL)
;

CREATE TABLE restaurant_has_pizzas
    (`restaurant_id` INT NOT NULL,
     `pizza_id` INT NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`restaurant_id`, `pizza_id`),
     CONSTRAINT `fk_restaurant_has_pizzas_restaurants1`
       FOREIGN KEY (`restaurant_id`)
       REFERENCES `restaurants` (`id`),
     CONSTRAINT `fk_restaurant_has_pizzas_pizzas1`
       FOREIGN KEY (`pizza_id`)
       REFERENCES `pizzas` (`id`))
;
INSERT INTO restaurant_has_pizzas
    (`restaurant_id`, `pizza_id`)
VALUES
    (1, 1),
    (1, 2),
    (1, 3),
    (1, 4),
    (1, 5),
    (2, 6),
    (1, 7),
    (2, 8),
    (2, 9)
;
```

See also [this **SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/eae31/1). Award-winning ingredients are only “peanuts” for “Don Camillo” and “root beer” for “Tasty Pizzas”. I don’t want to see the other ingredients which are currently returned by the SQL query. This is the expected result table:

```
name         | secret_ingredient
-------------|------------------
Don Camillo  | peanuts
Tasty Pizzas | root beer
```

#### Background

Ok, this is admittedly just a crafted example based on a more complex real life DB schema … but the latter was just too boring compared with my restaurant empire to show it here :-)

Comment: Ah, I have never used SQL Fiddle, thanks for the tip! I’ve added one now.

Comment: Do you mean the “desired result set” step? That’s described in the text I have added below the DDL. Or do you recommend to add any further information?

Comment: @Strawberry Not sure if that’s what you are after but I have added an expected result table above.

Comment: I have added foreign key constraints where available and updated the SQL Fiddle accordingly. I guess one challenge is that there is _no explicit relation_ between `pizzas` and `awarded_prizes`; instead, this relation has to somehow be derived from the timestamps as specified in the comment in the query.

Comment: An ingredient is part of a pizza, i.e., a column (`secret_ingredient`) in the `pizzas` table. But an award _is not explicitly_ related with a pizza; _implicitly_, though, an award is related to a certain pizza with a certain ingredient – via the timestamps. Sorry for this contrived example; our data model is quite specific to our internal processes so I have tried to invent a minimalistic example that I figured would be easier to understand for others …

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT a.name
      , b.secret_ingredient 
   FROM 
      ( SELECT r.*
             , MAX(p.created_at) max_created_at 
          FROM restaurants r 
          JOIN awarded_prizes z 
            ON z.id = r.latest_prize_id 
          JOIN pizzas p 
            ON p.created_at <= z.won_at 
         GROUP 
            BY r.id
      ) a 
   JOIN pizzas b 
     ON b.created_at = a.max_created_at;
 +--------------+-------------------+
 | name         | secret_ingredient |
 +--------------+-------------------+
 | Don Camillo  | peanuts           |
 | Tasty Pizzas | root beer         |
 +--------------+-------------------+
```

I'm not convinced that either of these ingredients belong anywhere near a pizza.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer has led me to the solution I needed. I have just edited your query to add a few more constraints in order to also make it work for larger datasets. If you accept my edits as part of your answer, then I’d be happy to mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: My answer answers the question that was asked, so no, I can't accept your edits.